# Integrating Paypal classic API

Tags: php, paypal

I have made an e-commerce website, but unfortunately I am stuck here when I want to integrate Paypal classic API with my live site. Though I have tested the integration with sandbox which is success, but when I tried to go live it keep returning error. The error I caught is :

```
Array
(
    [Errors] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Receiver] => 
                    [Category] => Application
                    [Domain] => PLATFORM
                    [ErrorID] => 550001
                    [ExceptionID] => 
                    [Message] => User is not allowed to perform this action
                    [Parameter] => 
                    [Severity] => Error
                    [Subdomain] => Application
                )

        )

)
```

and my classic API information is this :

### Adaptive Payment

Basic Payment

1.Checkout, Send Money or Parallel Payments

2.Currency Conversion

3.Get Payment Details

4.Refunds or Chargebacks

### Confirm Funding Sources You Support

1.Credit Card Payments

2.E-Checks

3.PayPal Balance

### Adaptive Accounts

Basic Payment

1.Create Business Accounts

I and the Classic API status right now is : "Approved Conditionally".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like from all of the information provided that the application has not been fully approved. I recommend calling in to PayPal support to check the status of the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to https://www.paypal-apps.com/ and log into your PayPal account. Click 'My Messages' to send your request to PayPal App team. They will review your case and get back to you.